# How can I generate a list of combinations of string joins?

Tags: string-manipulation

Suppose I have the string lists `{'a','b','c'}` and `{'1','2','3'}`. How do I get Mathematica to generate the list `{'a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3'}`?

Comment: Note that none of the lists in your question contain strings.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
a = {"a", "b", "c"};
n = {"1", "2", "3"};
StringJoin @@@ Tuples[{a, n}]
```

Answer (score 16):

```
m = {"a", "b", "c"};
n = {"1", "2", "3"};

Catenate[Outer[StringJoin, m, n]]
```

> {"a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}

Answer (score 14):

```
alist = {"a", "b", "c"};
nlist = {"1", "2", "3"};
Flatten@Outer[StringJoin, alist, nlist]
```

> {"a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}

---

For further study:

```
Join @@ (StringJoin @@@ Thread[Join[{#}, {nlist}]] & /@ alist)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Distribute[{alist,nlist},List,List,List,StringJoin]

(* {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3} *)
```

where

```
alist = {"a", "b", "c"};
nlist = {"1", "2", "3"};
```

Answer (score 9):

```
alist = {"a", "b", "c"};
nlist = {"1", "2", "3"};

Flatten@Table[alist[[i]] <> nlist[[j]], {j, 1, Length@nlist}, {i, 1, Length@alist}]
```

> {"a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}